# Azure APIM - Uploading large file performing slower in APIM compared to underlying API

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-api-management

I have an Azure app service that uploads files to azure blob storage. The app service also sits behind an instance of Azure API Management.

For a 200 MB file, if I upload via app service from my laptop, it completes in ~60 sec.
For the same file, if I upload via APIM from my laptop, it times out after 5 min.

The timeout is expected, as there is a setting for it.
APIM, app service and storage all reside in same geo location.

Is there some kind of throttling in place at APIM level?  Why would it be 5x or more slower than direct API call?

Comment: Looks like this is limited to our international users.  Local users aren't experiencing this issue.